# Continuity of the orthogonal matrix-valued function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, continuity, banach-spaces

Given $d<k$. Suppose that $H:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow {\cal M}(\mathbb{R})_{d,k}$ is a continuous matrices-valued function such that $H(x)$ is full rank for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Now define a function $K:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow  {\cal M}(\mathbb{R})_{k,k-d}$ such that $K(x)$ is full rank and
\begin{equation}
H(x)K(x)=0, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k.
\end{equation}

I'd like to prove that $K$ is also continuous.
I tried bounding $\|K(x)-K(y)\|$ from above using 
\begin{align}
\left\|\{H(x)-H(y)\}\{K(x)-K(y)\}\right\|&=\|H(x)K(y)+H(y)K(x)\| \\.
\end{align}
But then I don't now the lower bound of $\left\|\{H(x)-H(y)\}\right\|$. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: When you write $\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^k$, do you mean the set of $n \times k$ real matrices? I'd suggest something like $M_{n,k}(\mathbb R)$ for that instead. The thing you've written consists of ordered pairs $(v, w)$ where $v$ is a $d$-vector and $w$ is a $k$-vector, and I don't see how to treat that as a matrix.

Comment: I think that you meant also to say something about matrices being orthogonal or nonsingular or *something*. If not, then for $k = 1, d = 2$, take the function $H(x) = [0, 0]$, and let $K$ be any discontinuous function; that example would show that your conjecture is false.

Comment: Yes @john. Thanks again. What I have are $H$ and $K$ full rank matrices

Comment: When you write $M_{d, k}$, you mean "$d$ rows and $k$ columns," right? For the function $K$, do you really mean $M_{k, k-d}$ as the codomain? Or did you mean $M_{k, d-k}$. In particular, is $k \ge d$ or $k \le d$? If you mean what you wrote, then the conjecture looks wrong. Pick k=2, d=1 and $H(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Let $w: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be any discontinuous but nonzero function, and let $K(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ w(x)\end{bmatrix}$. Then $HK = 0$. But maybe I'm still not understanding things.

Comment: OK @john. Thanks for your help. I have restated my problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644635/continued-matrices-valued-function)