# Continued matrices-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, continuity, banach-spaces, grassmannian

Given $d<k$. Let ${\cal M}_{d\times k}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all $d\times k$ real matrices and suppose that $H:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow {\cal M}_{d\times k}(\mathbb{R})$ is a continuous matrices-valued function such that $H(x)$ is full rank for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

I'd like to construct a continuous function $K:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow  {\cal M}_{k\times (k-d)}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $K(x)$ is full rank and
\begin{equation}
H(x)K(x)=0, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k.
\end{equation}
Can we do that?

I've tried defining $K$ as follows: for every $x_0$ define $K(x_0)$ by such matrix with columns are all element in the basis of the subspace $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k :H(x_0)y=0\}$. Of course $K(x_0)\in {\cal M}_{k\times (k-d)}(\mathbb{R})$ since $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^k :H(x_0)y=0\}$ has dimension $k-d$. But the problem was on the continuity because we can choose arbritary basis of the above subspace. Can anyone give advice in constructing $K$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stupid question: $\forall x: K(x)=0$ (zero matrix) is OK?

Comment: Oh no... It has to be full rank for each $x$. I've made an edit now. Thanks @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: I think I see a way how to construct such function locally. You take a point $x_0$ and pick any $(k-d)$ linear independent vectors that are not in linear span of $\hat{H}(x_0) = H^{T}(x_0)$. Let's call them $\hat{K}$, $\hat{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times (k-d)}$. You can apply something like Gramm-Schmidt procedure to these vectors to make them orthogonal to $H(x)$: formula $K(x) = \hat{K} - \hat{H}(x) \left (\hat{H}^{T}(x) \hat{H}(x) \right)^{-1} \hat{H}^{T}(x) \hat{K}$ does the job. This formula works in some neighbourhood of point $x_0$.

Comment: ... but this reasoning heavily depends on continuity of inverse of $\hat{H}^{T}(x) \hat{H}(x)$

Comment: OK thanks @Evgeny. How is about my construction?

Comment: @Jlamprong My construction (in some sense) was modification of your construction. I've just tried to find some kind of explicit procedure that constructs basis for orthogonal complement of $H(x)$ continuously depending on $x$.

Comment: Btw, I actually want a function $K$ such that for every $x$ the function $K$ is bounded in some neighborhood $x$. Is it easier @Evgeny?

Comment: @Jlamprong If I understood last case correctly ($K(x)$ is just bounded, not necessarily continuous), you can just make columns of $K(x)$ equal to orthonormal basis of orthogonal complement of $H(x)$. It will always have Frobenius norm equal to $(k-d)$, so bounded. Also, may I ask you, where did you find this problem?

Comment: @Evgeny: Thanks for your help. This problem is actually a part of my research. I am working in statistics. The boundedness will be used to define my estimator.

Comment: @Evgeny: It turns out that I really need the continuity of $K$. Can we construct it?

Comment: I have to think. Also I would add $\rm (grassmaniann) $ tag to the question, because formulation of problem seems closely related to this topic.

Comment: OK @Evgeny. I am also thinking about the construction using basis of the kernel $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts on this question that are too lengthy for a comment. First, if you know any procedure that generates orthogonal vector for a given system of vectors and this procedure depends continuously on vectors of set (and depends only on vectors of this set) — it'll work here. You take vectors which are rows of $H(x)$, generate orthogonal vector $K_1$ and obtain matrix $( H\; \vert \; K_1)^{T}$ which is continuous w.r.t. to $x$. Then you repeat procedure and obtain vector $K_2$, append it again and repeat until you construct matrice $K(x) = (K_1, K_2, \dots, K_{k-d})$. I've tried to find such procedure, but hasn't succeed yet.

Also there's a further development of idea from comments, but it has a flaw. I'll use following notation:

- each point $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is equipped with $d$ vectors that form columns of matrix $\hat{H}(x) = H^{T}(x)$, $H(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k} $, $\hat{H}(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d} $;
- by $E$ denote the identity matrix, $E \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$;
- by $\Gamma (x)$ denote Gramm matrix, $\Gamma(x) = H(x)\cdot H^{T}(x)$, $\Gamma(x) \in {\mathbb R}^{d \times d}$.

Then you do the following. For each point compute matrix $\hat{K}(x) = E - \hat{H}(x) \cdot \Gamma^{-1}(x) \hat{H}^{T}(x)$. This transformation just takes a standard basis at each point $x$ (it corresponds to matrix $E$), subtracts from each basis vector its orthogonal projection on $\hat{H}(x)$ and makes a set of vectors from $\hat{H}^{\perp}(x)$. Matrix $\hat{K}(x)$ depends continuously on $x$ (multiplications/additions are continuous, inversion is continuous too). Also, it satisfies $\hat{H}(x)\hat{K}(x) \equiv 0$. The only problem (and this is the flaw that I've mentioned) is that $\hat{K}(x)$ is from $\mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{k \times (k-d)}$; but it surely has rank $(k-d)$. The problem that I'm struggling here is that I still don't know a way how to continuously "extract" some basis from set of columns of matrix $\hat{K}(x)$.

**EDIT**: Probably, that's [not always possible](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314613/when-can-one-continuously-prescribe-a-unit-vector-orthogonal-to-a-given-orthonor). I wonder if OP's original can be solved by any other method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Evgeny. Now, I have general idea in constructing such function. I'll think further about it. In my view, the gist of this problem is finding the $k-d$ vectors which are orthogonal with the rows of $H$, isn't it?

Comment: Kind of. Orthogonal interpretation was closer for me, so I've chosen it. The problem with last method is that it generates set of vectors which spans orthogonal complement to the span of matrix $H(x)$ rows, but this set is bigger than the basis set.